# How to Terminate VBA Sub from within called Function

Tags: excel, vba, exit

How do I get a VBA sub to exit from within a called function if an error occurs?

I've tried placing `Exit Sub` statements within the relevant functions, but whenever I save and re-open the file, VBA automatically changes it to `Exit Function`.

For example, how do I get the code below

```
Sub foo()
    userNum = userNum()

    MsgBox(var)
End Sub

Function userNum() As Integer
    userNum = InputBox("Enter your positive number")

    If var < 0 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid: your number must be positive.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Function
```

to not execute `MsgBox(var)`?

Comment: `userNum()` knows nothing about the callee `foo()`, so generally the only way to control the flow is to return some value and build a conditional statement within the sub. In this partucular case you may just use `End` instead of `Exit Sub`.

Comment: @omegastripes does using `End` by itself that work? I've searched the VBA dpcumentation and I can't find any mention of `End` without another keyword immediately after it. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-keyword-statement

Comment: `End` just terminates code execution. Like you press "stop" button in debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare variables.
2. I would recommend using `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=1` to accept numbers as input.
3. Declare the result as `Variant` so that you can handle the the `Cancel` button in the `InputBox`. Also use that to decide whether you want to show the number or not.

Is this what you are tying? (**Untested**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
    Dim numb As Variant
    numb = userNum()

    If numb <> False Then MsgBox numb
End Sub

Function userNum() As Variant
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter you number", Type:=1)

    If Ret = False Then
        userNum = False
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Ret < 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Invalid: your number must be positive.")
        userNum = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    userNum = Ret
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a more succint way of doing it that doesn't involve having the `If numb <> False Then ...` lines in the sub? Similar to what I have in my question.

Comment: `If numb <> False` handles both the situation when the user presses cancel as well as any negative numbers. If you wanted number greater than 0 then it would have been a much simpler solution :)